# How to modify an array of strings with StringBuilder and then write them back to the same file I pulled the data from?

Tags: c#

Current code is attempting to pull data line by line from test.txt and then use StringBuilder to modify each individual line with the appropriate edits before writing the data back to the same file I pulled the original data from. I can't wrap my head around why I am getting empty strings in my array when each line in my test file is roughly 200 characters in length. When I attempt to compile I get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException when it reaches the following line of code:

```
            Editor.Remove(11, 14);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Code Snippet:

```
        var SecondPath = @"C:\\test.txt"; //creates a variable pointing to my test file.
        string[] MoreLines = File.ReadAllLines(SecondPath); // takes that file and puts each line into its own string

        DateTime Current = DateTime.Today; // gets current date
        string Conversion = Current.ToString("s"); //converts date into a string in the format of yyyy-mm-dd


        foreach (string S in MoreLines) //takes each individual string and edits that string using Stringbuilder
        {
            StringBuilder Editor = new StringBuilder();

            Editor.Insert(0, "0");
            Editor.Insert(1, "0");
            Editor.Remove(11, 14); //<==Current Problem, previous answer not applicable
            Editor.Insert(11, "R");
            Editor.Insert(12, "M");
            Editor.Insert(13, "A");
            Editor.Insert(14, "L");
            Editor.Insert(15, "L");
            Editor.Insert(16, " ");
            Editor.Insert(17, " ");
            Editor.Insert(18, " ");
            Editor.Insert(28, Conversion); // <== Hoping I implemented this right.
            Editor.Append("CL");  // Supposed to add 'CL' to the end of each line.

        }

File.WriteAllLines(SecondPath, MoreLines); //If my understanding is correct, this should write back to my test file all the changes the String Builder performed.
```

Comment: If you step through the code with a debugger it becomes very apparent what the problem is.

Comment: well, did you look at [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.remove%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? ArgumentOutOfRangeException is thrown `if startIndex or length is less than zero, or startIndex + length is greater than the length of this instance.`  What didn't you understand?

Comment: You need to debug your own code before asking.  Simply setting a break point and stepping through line by line will show you the problem in less time than it took you to ask this question.

Comment: I was aware that my `StringBuilder` is editing an empty string before asking this question. What I was hoping to discover is why my StringBuilder is not being populated with the data from each string in my array.

Comment: @LanSlyde Because you cerate a new `Editor` each time without using `S`.

Comment: @LanSlyde Why *should* the string builder be populated with the text of your line?  How is it supposed to know that you want it populated with that value?  If you want to populate the stringbuilder with the current line of text, you'll need to write the code to indicate that that's what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code above, you need to initialize your `StringBuilder` to the line you're reading, otherwise you can't access items that you haven't added explicitly! Also, you aren't doing anything with it when you're done, so it appears you're writing back the same contents that you read in the first place.

Below is an example of how I would do it. I'm using two `StringBuilders`: one inside the `foreach` loop, which is initialized to the value of the current line and then modified using the `Insert`, `Remove`, and `Append` methods; and another one outside of the `foreach` loop, which represents all the new (modified) lines to write back to the file.

Note that at the end of the loop I append each 'line' `StringBuilder` to the 'file' `StringBuilder`:

```
var filePath = @"C:\test.txt";

var newFileText = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(filePath))
{
    var newLine = new StringBuilder(line);

    newLine.Insert(0, "0");
    newLine.Insert(1, "0");
    newLine.Remove(11, 14);
    newLine.Insert(11, "R");
    newLine.Insert(12, "M");
    newLine.Insert(13, "A");
    newLine.Insert(14, "L");
    newLine.Insert(15, "L");
    newLine.Insert(16, " ");
    newLine.Insert(17, " ");
    newLine.Insert(18, " ");
    newLine.Insert(28, DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    newLine.Append("CL");

    newFileText.AppendLine(newLine.ToString());
}

File.WriteAllText(filePath, newFileText.ToString());
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, you want to save this as a *.dat (binary format) file. Here's how:

```
// Re-using the same path as 'filePath' above, just adding a new file name/extension
var datFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath), "test.dat");

// Create a new file with the new name
using (FileStream file = File.Create(datFilePath))
{
    // Write the newFileText StringBuilder text to the file with a BinaryWriter
    using (var binaryFile = new BinaryWriter(file))
    {
        binaryFile.Write(newFileText.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: That works a great deal better than what I was trying. Now to figure out how to convert my text file to a DAT file.

Comment: Added a sample to save it as a binary .dat file

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized your `StringBuilder` to be the line in question.  It's blank in your case.  You need to populate it with the current line's text.

Comment: Alright, I understand what your telling me, but I am unsure how to implement that. How could I populate StringBuilder with data? I thought I did so when I implemented the `foreach` loop. Would I have to add additional information to `StringBuilder Editor = new StringBuilder();`?

Comment: @LanSlyde See the documentation for `StringBuilder` (or just look at your own code) to see how you can populate it with a `string` value.